# Razorpay error "Account Id is required with partner credential"

Tags: android, payment-gateway, razorpay

I am trying to integrate Razorpay to the android app. I am getting the following error whenever I open the checkout form.

```
{"code":"BAD_REQUEST_ERROR","description":"Account id is required with partner credentials"}
```

I am setting the Key Id in `checkout.setKeyID(keyId)`. I also have an account Id, but do not know where to set it.

Comment: I am also getting the same error using web SDK, any solution?

Comment: Check answer posted. It works

Answer (score 0):

Pass `account_id` along with `currency` in Json object